# Sql Server audit could not write to the security log

Tags: sql-server, audit

I am following the training kit for `70-462(Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Databases)`, and stuck on `Auditing SQL Server instances` lesson. I have created new user in domain controller, assign it `Generate Security audits` and `Log on as a service rights`. Then I installed `SQL Server` instance on one of the machine in the domain with this account. I checked installed instance service and it is started under this account. I have also followed the steps here http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/resolving-error-33204-sql-server-audit-could-not-write-to-the-security-log/.

But when I am enabling the audit it logs the error:

> Sql Server audit could not write to the security log

```
Version: SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60(X64) Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64>(Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

What else can I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little bit silly, but after restarting the machine audit was enabled without any problem.

Comment: Was some service/process not restarted after getting more rights?

Comment: @Colin'tHart, may be. I don't know for sure. May be restarting sql service would also do the thing. I should check.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about Windows semantics, but I can imagine that a user's session doesn't inherit new rights until after it logs in again -- and that includes processes run as a service which are "logging in" as some special user. That would explain why restarting the server fixed your problem!